# React Data Grid does not keep changes after un-filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to work with React Data Grid.
When I filter my table, make a change to a cell, then unfilter the table, the change reverts back to its previous value.
If I change
const rows = this.state.rows.slice(0);
to
const rows = Selectors.getRows(this.state);
my changes stay, but then I can not unfilter the table.

Here is how I am handling Grid Rows to Update:

```js
  handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
    const rows = this.state.rows.slice(0);
    // const rows = Selectors.getRows(this.state);
    
    for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
      const rowToUpdate = rows[i];
      const updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
      rows[i] = updatedRow;
      if (!rows[i].Date) {
        const index = this.state.counter;
        newRows[index] = rows[i];
        this.handleUpdate(rows[i]);
        this.setState({ newRows });
      } else {
        updatedRows[rows[i].Date] = rows[i];
        this.handleUpdate(rows[i]);
        this.setState({ updatedRows });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ originalRows: rows });
  };
```

I have looked at the RDG docs and examples. In their filter example, they don't allow you to edit cells.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a demo please? https://codepen.io

Comment: I'm trying to put together an example on codepen, but I can not get a react data grid with a filter to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, I used the npm library Lodash and their function _.unionBy.

This solution merges the updated rows array with the original states' rows array, on the SN key for each object, into a variable then sets the state with the result:

```js
 handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
    const rows = Selectors.getRows(this.state);
    const rowsTwo = Object.assign([], this.state.rows);
    
    for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
      const rowToUpdate = rows[i];
      const updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
      rows[i] = updatedRow;
      if (!rows[i].Date) {
        const index = this.state.counter;
        newRows[index] = rows[i];
        this.handleUpdate(rows[i]);
        this.setState({ newRows });
      } else {
        updatedRows[i] = rows[i];
        this.handleUpdate(rows[i]);
      }
    }
    const result = _.unionBy(updatedRows, rowsTwo, 'SN');
    
    this.setState({ rows: result });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

the state is unmutable, its a bad idea to keep slicing data as that, before you need to make a copy and then manipulate it, thus you can do

```
const rows = Object.assign([],this.state.rows)
```

btw a living example or the type of data your holding on rows will be a great help

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I gave this a try, but I am getting the same results.
I'm not sure how to get a living example out to you guys, I'm working in a private repo and the web app is hosted on an internal web server.
I can paste in my entire table code if needed.